# Unable to include table header in my script

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to scrape a table from a webpage. When I run my script, it does fetch the table. However, the only issue I'm facing at this moment is my scraper misses to parse the "th" tag from that table. I've already denoted that "th" tag in my script for your consideration which is commented out. How can I mend that line to get the full content of that table? If I uncomment that line and run now, It catches the following error:

```
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: 'value' must be a string
```

Elements within which the table elements lies can be seen clicking on the link:
"https://www.dropbox.com/s/cytp4m0m00dmu2f/Table%20elements.txt?dl=0"

The script I've tried with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("http://www.hko.gov.hk/cis/dailyExtract_e.htm?y=2015&m=1")

time.sleep(5)

table_data = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='t1']")

list_rows = []

for items in table_data.find_elements_by_xpath(".//tr"):

    list_cells = []

    for item in items.find_elements_by_xpath('.//td[@class="td1_normal_class" or @class="td1_year_class"]'):
    # for item in items.find_elements_by_xpath(['.//th[@class="td_normal_class"]', './/td[@class="td1_normal_class" or @class="td1_year_class"]']):

        list_cells.append(item.text)

    list_rows.append(list_cells)

for data in list_rows:

    print(data)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: What do you think this `['.//th[@class="td_normal_class"]'` should do? Note that first single quote is inside of square brackets and second- outside

Comment: Thanks sir Andersson, for your kind reply. It's always a great pleasure to have you in the loop. I did it intentionally. I tried to follow this pattern (['th','td']). Anyways, if you take a closer look, I tried like this- (['.//th[@class="td_normal_class"]', './/td[@class="td1_normal_class" or @class="td1_year_class"]']). The square braces i used above is for surrounding the whole pattern within it. Thanks again, sir.

Comment: Can you share exact output you want to get?

Comment: The output what I wanted and now I'm getting can be seen following the link. "https://www.dropbox.com/s/29ujyfsenr8ymf4/tab_data.csv?dl=0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to pass a list of values to `find_elements_by...()` while it should be a string. If you want your `XPath` to match both `th` or `td` try below line:

```
items.find_elements_by_xpath('.//th[@class="td_normal_class"] | .//td[@class="td1_normal_class" or @class="td1_year_class"]')
```

Comment: Thanks sir, Andersson for you effective solution. I've already got the output I wanted using your rectified xpath.